# How can I tell what DNS server is actually being used (Windows 10, sort of)?

Tags: dns

With my Windows 10 laptop, I go to a friend's house and encounter errors that well-known hosts like Google.com or Microsoft.com cannot be found (don't have the exact message, it basically says the IP address for Google.com cannot be found).

When I click `Properties` on the `Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)` item for my network adapter, it shows as selected  `Obtain DNS server address automatically` (as well as `Obtain an IP address automatically`).

Is there a way to find out what DNS server is actually being used? I'll guess that this question as written may actually be moot, since my laptop has ethernet plugged into the ISP-provided ZyXEL VMG4825 B10A DSL modem/router. So it might be the case that Windows will just use the router's local address, `192.168.1.1` for DNS queries.

What I'm really trying to find out is what address the router is using - it has a setting for DNS that is either PROXY or ISP, and I have tried both with intermittent success and failure on each one. What I'd like to do is be able to tell the ISP (Consolidated Communications) that their DNS server is broken, but without an IP address, I doubt they'll listen to me, they just keep telling me internet service to my friend's house is fine.

I guess I could just skip the complaint, and manually set the DNS server in Windows to `8.8.8.8` or something, but I'd like to know what the problem really is. I suppose if `8.8.8.8` works reliably, that would be "proof" that the problem, is (one of) the ISP's DNS server(s), but again I doubt they would listen to that.

Any advice?

Comment: Instead of adapter Properties, rightclick adapter / **Status** / Details . Or in CMD or Powershell `ipconfig /all` or in Powershell only `get-netipconfiguration` . But as you say, if Windows is using the router, that gives you no clue what the router is using.

Comment: when you use the command" nslookup ipaddress/domainname" it will show which DNS server you use to resolve